# How can I see what list items are in what folder?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, splistitem, folder

I have some code that shows me all the items (files and folders) in a document library, but everything appears on the same level. How can I see which items sit in which folders?

Currently the output looks something like this:

```
folder 1 -> folder
folder 2 -> folder
folder 3 -> folder
item 1-1 -> item
item 1-2 -> item
item 2-1 -> item
item 3-1 -> item
item 3-2 -> item
```

Where item 1-1 and 1-2 are in folder 1, item 2-1 in folder 2 and item 3-1 and 3-2 in folder 3.

```
function FindItems() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();

    var cqy = new SP.CamlQuery();
    cqy.set_viewXml("<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /></ViewFields><RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>");     

    var items = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Site Pages').getItems(cqy);

    ctx.load(items, 'Include(Title,FileSystemObjectType,DisplayName,FileLeafRef)');

    ctx.executeQueryAsync( 
        function () {
            var itemEnum = items.getEnumerator();

            while (itemEnum.moveNext()) {
                var item = itemEnum.get_current();

                var itemTitle = item.get_item('FileLeafRef');
                var itemType  = ( item.get_fileSystemObjectType() == 1 ? 'folder' : 'item' );
                console.log( itemTitle + ' -> ' + itemType );
            }
        },
        function(sender,args){
            console.log('Error: ' + jQuery.param(args));
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find folder name from `ServerUrl` of your document. It should look like

```
"/{LibraName}/{FolderName}/{fileName.extention}"
```

So the folder is always before the document.

## Coding Changes

```
cqy.set_viewXml("<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                 <ViewFields>
                   <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
                   <FieldRef Name='Title' /> 
                   <FieldRef Name='ServerUrl' />
                </ViewFields>
           <RowLimit>1000</RowLimit></View>");

ctx.load(items, 'Include(Title,FileSystemObjectType,DisplayName,FileLeafRef, ServerUrl)');
```